# check if javascript variable has been changed from console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a JS game and wish to prevent cheating as much as possible. I understand that this is near impossible but I would like to prevent users from going into the console and changing their lives by saying something like `game.lives = 99;`

Is there a way I can detect if a variable such as `lives` has been changed from the console thus marking the game hacked and stopping the execution of my code? I understand I could do server side checking but I want to avoid lag. I am looking for a JS answer if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to completely stop a user from changing the javascript code or variable values.  You only can make it more difficult.  Fisch mentioned using closure so as all variables will be private.  Look into the immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) pattern.  It's used in a lot of plugin style code and helps prevent modifications.

If a user wants to change a variables value, nothing will stop them from running the game in debug mode and modifying values at breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure which would essentially make all your variables private and thus not accessible from the console. If you need to have some public variables and methods, you could use a revealing module pattern.  you can read more about them here: http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-closures-and-the-module-pattern/

Comment: It's not that hard to put a breakpoint in a closure and modify a variable.